# My Download Servlet runs twice

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, download

I have a gwt web application with a download servlet and I count downloads of every file in my db. When user sends a download request to server, my download servlet runs twice and my download counter counts 2 every time. but the file that user has sent request for it, has been downloaded once. I don't know whay my servlet runs 2 time for 1 request.

my download servlet:

```
public class DownloadServlet extends HttpServlet {

 private static final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "c:\\update\\";
 private Connection con;

 @Override
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
         throws ServletException, IOException {

     Statement select=null;
     ResultSet result=null;

     try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/laplasdb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8","gwt","root");
        }catch(Exception ex){

        }
     String query = "SELECT * FROM TBL_Drive_Files WHERE id = '"+req.getParameter("fileid")+"'", filename="";
     InputStream filecontent=null;

     int filesize=0;
     try {
         select = con.createStatement();
         result = select.executeQuery(query);
         while (result.next()) {
             filename = result.getString(2);
             filesize = result.getInt(4);
             filecontent = result.getBinaryStream(5);
         }

         result.close();

     } catch(SQLException e) {
     }


     BufferedOutputStream output = null; 
     try { 

         resp.reset(); 
         resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream"); 
         resp.setContentLength(filesize); 
         resp.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\""); 
         output = new BufferedOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream()); 
         for(int data; (data=filecontent.read()) != -1;) { 
             output.write(data); 
         } 
         output.flush(); 

         query = "Update TBL_Drive_Files SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = '"+req.getParameter("fileid")+"'";
         try {
            select = con.createStatement();
            select.execute(query);              

            select.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


     } 
     catch (IOException e) { 

         e.printStackTrace(); 
     } 
     finally {
     }
 }
```

}

and in client side:

```
Button bd = new Button("Download", new ClickHandler(){
             public void onClick(ClickEvent event){
                final String link = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "download?fileid=3";

                RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET,link);

                try {
                     builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
                     public void onError(Request request, Throwable t) {
                        Window.alert("Error bei getExcel");
                    }
                    public void onResponseReceived(Request request,Response response){
                            int statuscode = response.getStatusCode();
                            if(statuscode == 200) {
                                    Window.Location.replace(link);
                      } else if(statuscode == 404) {
                        Window.alert("Service not available.");
                      }
                    }
                   });
                   } catch (RequestException re) {
                       Window.alert(re.toString());
                   }
             }
    });             
    RootPanel.get().add(bd);
```

Comment: out of topic. Close resources in funally block, use PreparedStatement in first query. Use specific method for update `executeUpdate`. Also I suggest you to read code convention

Comment: Maybe a good old run line by line can help you to find why the counter is incremented by 2. Check if the SQL query is run 2 times, or if it increments by 2, that could help you

Comment: I compiled code line by line, servlet runs 2 times. But I couldn't find which commands run servlet

Comment: Actually I think that the servlet is called twice to responds to 2 different request, let's find them..

Comment: I put my request code above. Is there any duplicate request?

Comment: I don't really figure out what is the context in the use of the client, is it used by a browser ? Because, the second request could be the one to get the website icon (favicon.ico)

Comment: I don't think so, because this event only occure in that case

Comment: So if you click the button again after the first download, it increments also by 2 ? That would definitely indicates that the problem lies inside your code, but I don't see that other request :(

Comment: when I click the button, my code runs 2 time!!!

Comment: Is that the entire code you're using ? Do you have other buttons ?

Comment: no, one button, one servlet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make two requests. One by calling `builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback()`
and the other in the callback with status 200 `Window.Location.replace(link)`

Btw i hope this isnt a code that will be deployed.

- Not handled exceptions
- Database operations should be done in an own layer
- I cant see any code convention
- You should only select the columns u realy need
- Unnecessary declarations

There are many other points, but you should fix this at first and then u will be able to find errors and maintain the code by yourself

Comment: when i remove Window.Location.replace(link) from my code, the servlet runs one time, but the download action doesn't work properly. so what can i do?

Comment: I dont know your requirements, but if its enough you could get rid of the requestBuilder and just use `Window.location.replace(...)`

See the manual (according to your errormessage, i think the german link is ok)
http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/location.htm#replace

Answer (score 0):

Taken from my answer to: [Download file using Jersey and RestyGWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720104/download-file-using-jersey-and-restygwt/17729413#17729413)

`In general(*) you cannot use ajax to download files, so you have to use a Window.open() or an iframe to ask the user to save the file as.`

So don't use `RequestBuilder` to get the file, and as I said at: [Window.open in GWT not open correctly with in a call back function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692221/window-open-in-gwt-not-open-correctly-with-in-a-call-back-function/17692398#17692398)

`The best solution, is to open the file in an iframe, but you have to set the appropriate content-disposition header in server side which causes the browser to show the "Save" dialog.`